# Django url redirect problem

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, django-registration

I use "django-registration" by James Bennett.
To hook up it to my project I have to write in my main url file:

```
(r'^users/', include('registration.urls')),
```

So then all urls of this app will be start with "users/". It isn't bad. But for "login" I want to use just home directory "/".

**How to do this without changing the "django-registration" source files?**
I tried to use "redirect_to" in my main url file:

```
    url('users/login/$',
    'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',
    {'url': 'login/'}),
```

But it just adds "login/" to the end of "users/login/" and I get "user/login/login/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should just add

```
(r'^login/', 'registration.views.name_of_login_view'),
```

to your project main urls.py.

Regarding your URL try using {'url': '/login/'} instead of {'url': 'login/'}

Answer (score 0):

```
{'url': '/login/'}),
```

Change 'login/' to '/login' to fix. Path starts with '/' means 'I will be added from home path, not current'.